# Flutter: persistentFooterButtons with equally dynamic size widgets

Tags: flutter

I want to create a persistentFooterButtons with 3 FlatButton.icon 
to equally take the whole width of the Screen, and customize itself with different screen sizes, i tried many approaches like Wrap,Expanded, i couldn't make it work, i even tried

`final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        Container(
            width: screenSize.width /3 ,
            child: FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: null,
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: Text("search")),
        ),`

but the text always overflows on the right side of the screen.
So, Any ideas how this might go?

## **Edit**

i found this approach which is very helpful

```
persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              new Text('Idea'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              new Text('Idea'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              new Text('Idea'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
```

The only problem is that `mainAxisAlignment` property doesn't make any changes, so the three buttons are sided together
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qrmx.png)

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

For create a persistentFooterButtons you need to use `bottomNavigationBar`.
And For create 3 flatButton with equal size, you need to use `flex` attribute inside `Expanded` Widget.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Center(child: Text("Flutter"),),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[

        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: Text("Search"),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: Text("Search"),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: Text("Search"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, Can u see the Edit i made?